Network routing between sites
From my attached diagram.
"Linux server 2" can access the internet but it can not ping "Linux server 1" at site A.
"Linux Gateway" at the same site as "Linux server 2" can ping "Linux server 1"
"Linux Gateway" has IPV4 forward enabled.
So why am I not getting a response from "Linux Server 1" when I ping from "Linux server 2".
Any help much appreciated
diagram

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your firewalls and routers show only one IP address, and according to your netmasks they are in different networks. Shouldn't these nodes have at least two IP addresses? Please [edit] your question and show the routing tables of Linux Gateway and Linux Server 1 and 2. I suggest to check witth a network sniffer, e.g. Wireshark, what packets you see on the path between Linux Server 2 and Linux Server 1.

thanks for you comment, revised the diagram. When you write routing tables is that the about from "route -n" that you are looking for ?

Yes, that's the routing table, but given that it's Linux, ip route would give more accurate output. What kind of VPN do you use – IPsec policy-based VPN (no network interface) or traditional route-based VPN (with its own tun0/vpn0/... interface)? If it's route-based, does the VPN connection have its dedicated subnet? (If it does, would be best to include it in the diagram.)

Does "Linux server 1" have tcpdump or tshark available? Install it and run tcpdump -n -i eth0 icmp and see what it shows while server 2 is trying to ping it.
